# How to limit the title of wordpress to specific categories?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to limit the title of wordpress for a particular category

I have this code to general limit the title of wordpress:

code in functions.php:

```
function titleLimitChar($title){
        if(strlen($title) > 30 && !(is_single()) && !(is_page())){ // not in single post page and page.
            $title = substr($title,0,30) . "..";
        }
        return $title;
    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'titleLimitChar' );
```

What should I add to the code to limit the title of wordpress to specific categories?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine for common title limitation. You have to add extra checking for your category in the method as

```
function titleLimitChar($title){
        if(is_category( '9' )){
            if(strlen($title) > 30 && !(is_single()) && !(is_page())){ // not in single post page and page.
                $title = substr($title,0,30) . "..";
            }
             return $title;
        }else{
         return $title;
        }   


    }
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'titleLimitChar' );
```

in the **is_category()** you use **category id**, **category name** and **catgory-slug** etc.

For Multiple categories just pass array in the parameter as

```
array( 9, 'blue-cheese', 'Stinky Cheeses' )
```

Other uses to check specific category or categories as below from the WordPress developer portal.

```
is_category();
// When any Category archive page is being displayed.

is_category( '9' );
// When the archive page for Category 9 is being displayed.

is_category( 'Stinky Cheeses' );
// When the archive page for the Category with Name "Stinky Cheeses" is being displayed.

is_category( 'blue-cheese' );
// When the archive page for the Category with Category Slug "blue-cheese" is being displayed.

is_category( array( 9, 'blue-cheese', 'Stinky Cheeses' ) );
```

Source : [Wp Developer is_category() function ;](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/)

Thank you!

Comment: It's great!. My problem is solved. Thank you Mr. Abu Muaz.

Comment: Great! You are Welcome & Glad to hear that your problem is solved.For any query feel free to  communicate.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**`wp_trim_words()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

This function trims text to a certain number of words and returns the trimmed text.

```
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 40, '...' );
```

Comment: Thank for your answered.